# Prove that classical counting requires $k=\Omega(N)$ oracle calls

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, grovers-algorithm, nielsen-and-chuang, classical-computing

> Consider a classical algorithm for the counting problem which samples uniformly and
> independently $k$ times from the search space, and let $X_1, ... ,X_k$ be the results of
> the oracle calls, that is, $X_j=1$ if the $j$ th oracle call revealed a solution to the
> problem, and $X_j=0$ if the $j^{th}$ oracle call did not reveal a solution to the problem. This algorithm returns the estimate $S≡N\times\sum_j X_j/k$ for the number of solutions to the search problem. Show that the standard deviation in $S$ is $\Delta S=\sqrt{M (N − M )/k}$. Prove that to obtain a probability at least $3/4$ of estimating $M$ correctly to within an accuracy $\sqrt{M}$ for all values of $M$ we must have $k=\Omega(N)$.

First part of this problem is attempted to prove in a similar post, named [Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 6.13: Standard deviation of classical counting algorithm](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/nielsen-chuang-exercise-6-13-standard-deviation-of-classical-counting-algorit), as

$$
E[S]=E\Big(N\times\sum_j X_j/k\Big)=\frac{N}{k}\times E\Big( \sum_jX_j \Big)=\frac{N}{k}\times \sum_j E(X_j)\\
$$
where we have $E(X_j)=1\times P(X_j=1)+0\times P(X_j=0)=P(X_j=1)=M/N$, therefore
$$
E[S]=\frac{N}{k}\times \sum_j \frac{M}{N}=\frac{N}{k}\times\frac{k\times M}{N}=M
$$
Similarly,
$$
(E[S^2])=E[(N\times\sum_j X_j/k)^2]=\frac{N^2}{k^2}(\sum_j X_j)^2=\frac{N^2}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k} X_iX_j
$$
Case 1 : $i=j$
$$
E(X_iX_j)=E(X_i^2)=P(X_i=1)=M/N
$$
Case 2 : $i\neq j$
$$
E(X_iX_j)=P(X_i=1,X_j=1)=P(X_i=1)P(X_j=1)=M^2/N^2
$$
Note that case 1 happens $k$ times, therefore case 2 happens $k^2-k$ times.
$$
\therefore\\
E(S^2)=\frac{N^2}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k} X_iX_j=\frac{N^2}{k^2}\bigg[k\frac{M}{N}+(k^2-k)\frac{M^2}{N^2}\bigg]=\frac{MN}{k}+M^2-\frac{M^2}{k}
$$
and therefore,
$$
Var(S)=E[S^2]-(E[S])^2=\frac{MN}{k}+M^2-\frac{M^2}{k}-M^2=\frac{M(N-M)}{k}\\
\implies \Delta(S)=\sqrt{M(N-M)/k}
$$

The remaining part is,

> Prove that to obtain a probability at least $3/4$ of estimating $M$ correctly to within an accuracy $\sqrt{M}$ for all values of $M$ we must have $k=\Omega(N)$.

How do I make sense of the remaining part of the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using Chebyshev's inequality,  $p(|S-E(S)|\geq\lambda\Delta(S))\leq1/\lambda^2$. To obtain a probability at least 3/4, let $\lambda=2$. We know that
$$p\left(|S-E(S)|\leq2\Delta S\right)\geq\frac{3}{4}$$
i.e.,
$$p\left(|S-M|\leq2\sqrt{\frac{M(N-M)}{k}}\right)\geq\frac{3}{4}$$
To make $2\sqrt{\frac{M(N-M)}{k}}$ be $O(\sqrt{M})$, $k$ has to be $\Omega(N-M)=\Omega(N)$.